# Curl aem Deployment environment variable

Tags: shell, curl, aem

I have the following shell script and it works by downloading artifacts from nexus and deploy to my aem server.

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://mynexus:8081/service/rest/beta/search/assets?repository=maven-releases&group=com.mypackage&maven.artifactId=mypackage&maven.extension=zip' > nexus
sed -i '/path/d' ./nexus
grep   zip  nexus | sort > zip
sed -E 's/.*(http[^"]*)".*/\1/g' ./zip | sed '$!d' > deploy
export DEPLOY=`cat deploy`
wget -i deploy

curl -u $user:$pass --fail  -F file=@"mypackage.zip" -F force=true -F install=true 'http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service.jsp'
```

Is there a way I can make this without specifying "mypackage.zip" and used environment variables in place as $DEPLOY.

I have tried this and it did not work.

```
curl -u $user:$pass --fail  -F file=@"$DEPLOY" -F force=true -F install=true 'http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service.jsp'
```

Comment: Didn't work, in what way? Which shell are you using? What is the value of $DEPLOY?

Comment: Hi Robin,  I am using bash shell and my echo $DEPLOY variables are set to http://mynexus:8081/repository/maven-releases/com/myrepo/apps/1.88/mypackage.zip. Basically issue here is that my log file show the correct variable package name and path but deployment to aem fails without any error.